# nasm gcc command error with subprogram as seperate file

Tags: linux, gcc, nasm

testing subprograms as external files in nasm. After running :

```
nasm -f elf subprogram2.asm
nasm -f elf get_int.asm
```

I then run the gcc:

```
gcc subprogram2.o get_int.o -o stuff.exe
```

I then get the following error:

```
subprogram2.o: In function 'main':
subprogram2.asm:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to 'get_int'
subprogram2.asm:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to 'get_int'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`section .text` of the file containing `main` has both the `extern get_int` and `global get_int`

and I am using a call and return for the subprogram in my `main`.
I will also point out I am running this on a vm on 32-bit ubuntu linux.

Comment: Sounds like the problem is in get_int.asm.  Is 'get_int' global there too?

Comment: As @DavidWohlferd hinted, the `global label` directive should go into the file that exports the label, not into the files that want to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [NASM manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc6.html):

> `GLOBAL` is the other end of `EXTERN`: if one module declares a symbol as `EXTERN` and refers to it, then in order to prevent linker errors, some other module must actually define the symbol and declare it as `GLOBAL`.

So if `get_int` is defined in get_int.asm you should put the `global get_int` in get_int.asm, and declare it as `extern` in any other files that want to use `get_int`.